# Task scheduler does not start (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

My service `Task Scheduler` is not running. In `Services` it is stopped. When trying to start it, it stops immediately.

In the eventlog has no entries about this service, not about it starting, stopping or errors.

The two services it is depending on, `Remote Procedure Call` and `System Events Broker`, are both running.

Starting up application `Task Scheduler` from the Windows menu, will produce the error message `The remote computer was not found`.

I run `sfc /scannow`. It did not find any integrity violations.

Any suggestions are very welcome.

*Additional information:*

- Windows 10 Pro v 1803 (OS Build 17134.706)
- PC is not part of a domain, but part of a workgroup
- Virusscanner has run: no virusses

*** UPDATE ***

I removed all tasks from `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks` and rebooted. After starting the service I got the event message: `Task Scheduler service failed to start due to an error in "JobStore::CreateJobStore" . Additional Data: Error Value: 2147943714.` This was about the missing tasks, so I restored them again.

Now, when I try to start the service, it stops again without any message in the eventlog.

Comment: Yes, I rebooted it several times. Logon As is set to `Local System`, which is grayed out. I am running Avast-virusscanner right now.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT: My computer is virus free.

Comment: Disable the AV and see if the Task Scheduler will start. If so, then that would indicate the AV software is blocking something with that service, etc.

Comment: What happened that made it stop working?

Comment: Also, if you go to Task Scheduler does it open and if so consider going to **View** | **Show Hidden Tasks** and then try to backup all your important tasks. Now delete all the tasks, restart the PC, and then see if the Task Scheduler starts working again. You say the service fails to start but wasn't sure if the Task Scheduler GUI management still allowed you in so you could purge the jobs in case it's a corrupt job causing the service to fail. You should be able to copy the `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks` folder for a backup too.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT: I already removed all tasks (after backing up). It produced new errors, but it still did not start. The option `Show Hidden Tasks` does not work, because then the service needs to be running.